# How to update non null column field using prepareStatement in Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for programming in Java and it's connected to mySql. I tried updating (using textfields t1 and t2) a column field (stockist_id(not null)) using prepare statement but it gives an error

> stockist_id cannot be null.

```
pst=con.prepareStatement("update stockist set stockist_id=? where     
stockist_name=?");
pst.setString(2,t2.getSelectedText());
pst.setString(1,t1.getSelectedText());
```

Comment: did you check what is the value return by `t1.getSelectedText()`

Comment: @Gaurav are you still having the problem? If so pass some string like this `pst.setString(1,"mytest");` and test your code.

Comment: I solved the by myself.Actually I was using getSelectedText() for a JTextField.Instead I should be using getText().